# In Excel have a cell read specific text when two others equal a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet containing some budgets. In one of my tables there are three columns that indicate if two parties have paid their share of money. Column 1 shows if person B has paid their amount, and column two shows if person G has paid theirs. What I'm trying to do is get column 3 to change from PENDING to YES when BOTH parties have paid and I can change the cells in column 1 and 2 from saying NO to BOTH saying YES.

(I've included a picture of what I'm trying to achieve in my spreadsheet below)

I'm sure there is an easy formula for this, but I can't work out how to do it! I've managed to already get the cells to colour code to a corresponding word through conditional formatting, and have a feeling I need to do something along these lines, but can't figure it out.

[image: Spreadsheet Example]

Comment: It's not entirely clear whenever you want to change column one and two to manually change to yes in order to column three automatically change or if you want to be able to change column three and automatically change column one and two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

> =IF(AND([@[B Paid]]="yes",[@[G Paid]]="yes"),"yes","pending")

The IF statement gives you logic to determine what the column value should be ("yes" or "pending").

The AND statement evaluates whether both columns are "yes", in which case it returns as "true" otherwise it returns "false".

Comment: Great, glad it helped.  Would you please consider ticking the green checkmark to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

While in the column 3 cell go to formulas on the top ribbon and then click on text and then EXACT. Text 1 will be the column 1 cell and text 2 will be the column 2 cell.
[Image of where to go in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxCP1.jpg)